# How can I get attribute of attribute in python from json?

Tags: python, json

I encountered a simple problem while learning python and I can't find the answer to it.

Say we have a json:

```
{
"Meta Data": {
   "random": "random"
},
"Time Series (1min)": {
    "2020-03-31 16:00:00": {
        "1. open": "523.1900",
        "2. high": "524.9000",
        "3. low": "523.1000",
        "4. close": "524.5200",
        "5. volume": "138425"
    },
    "2020-03-31 15:59:00": {
        "1. open": "522.0100",
        "2. high": "523.8900",
        "3. low": "522.0100",
        "4. close": "523.4100",
        "5. volume": "82971"
    }
 }
 }
```

Now I want to get all of the "close" attributes from this json as a list of strings, how can I do this using python 3.7 ?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55758778/python-to-get-value-from-nested-dictionary-wherever-given-key-found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want to use close attributes value.

Modified [brunns's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55758879/6660373) code:

```
def get_value(d, k):
    keys_value = []
    if k in d.keys():
        return d[k]
    for key, value in d.items():
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            item = get_value(value, k)
            if item:
#                 print(item)
                keys_value.append(item)
    return keys_value
```

---

```
vals = get_value(js, '4. close')[0]
vals
```

---

**Output:**

```
['524.5200', '523.4100']
```

Here js is your input JSON.

Comment: Thank you very much, with some modifications my code work just fine, could you please tell me why is there a `[0]` at `vals = get_value(js, '4. close')[0]` also I'm kinda noob with py, but should I name my functions with snake case as you did?
Thanks for the solution!

Comment: this `get_value(js, '4. close')` returns `[['524.5200', '523.4100']]` that's why used [0] to get only `['524.5200', '523.4100']`

Answer (score 1):

1) extract the dict that you need to get data from
2) loop through the dict, get the key that ends with ‘close’ and then just retrieve the value for that key. You can do the whole thing in 1 line
3) the output is a list of close values

```
data=json.loads(jsondata)
tm_data = data['Time Series (1min)']
close_items = [value[internalvalue] for key,value in tm_data.items() for internalvalue in value.keys() if internalvalue.endswith('close')]
```

Comment: Please add a few sentences to explain what your code is doing, so you can get more upvotes for your answer.